# How to do mvn dependency:tree for an uber jar?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, uberjar

I am analysing a repo to determine all the dependencies, *mvn dependency:tree -V* works great for this. A particular repo includes an unshaded [uber jar](http://fiji.sc/Uber-JAR) where all the dependency jars have been unpacked & repacked into a single jar.

Running *mvn dependency:tree -V* on this repo does not list the nested dependencies in the uber jar.

Looking at the uber jar pom it is not conclusive since the dependencies listed pull in other dependencies (which is where *mvn dependency:tree -V* is otherwise great).

Any ideas on how I can see all the dependencies (including versions) used in the uber jar since *mvn dependency:tree -V* does not work for it?

Comment: If you have the pom that created the uber-jar I'm not sure what the issue is--doing a dependency tree on that pom should list the recursive dependencies, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that *mvn dependency:tree -V* does not go inside the uber jar. I needed to go to the repo for the uber jar and do a *mvn dependency:tree -V
* there.